# Flexslider - show name of image as a tooltip while mouse hover on dots

Tags: javascript, jquery, flexslider

I am using http://flexslider.woothemes.com/ flex slider plugin in my page. Below is my code for flexslider:

```
<div class="flexslider">
    <ul class="slides">
        <li> <p> Apple</p><img src="apple.jpg"/> </li>
        <li> <p> Banana </p><img src="banana.jpg"/> </li>
        <li> <p> Orange </p> <img src="orange.jpg"/> </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Javascript code for flex slider and this code is used to initialize the flex slider while page load.

This is my flexslider load function:

```
$(window).load(function() {
    $('.flexslider').flexslider({   
        animation: "slide",
        slideshow: false,
        controlNav: true,
        directionNav: false,
        easing: "swing"
    });
});
```

All I want two things:

- On mouse hover to dots (which used for navigation among slides) a tool tip should render and show the name of image. Example: Orange image is @ 3rd slide so when user mouse hover to that dot tooltip should show "Orange" and similarly for other slides too.
- When i click a dot, i should able to pass the name image to call a AJAX (java script) function and once that function is complete, then the slide should get render.

Please help me to provide the solution for above two use-cases.

Comment: Are you using Bootstrap?

Comment: I am using http://flexslider.woothemes.com/ flex slider plugin in my jsp page